Error with topaz.SigUsb java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\bin\SigUsb.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
I am developing a Java application that uses SigUsb.dll for interfacing with a digital signature device. However, I am encountering a java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError stating that dependent libraries cannot be found, The exact error message is:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\bin\SigUsb.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
I have confirmed that SigUsb.dll is a 64-bit DLL and my Java version is also 64-bit. I tried adding the DLL to C:\Windows\System32 and setting up the java.library.path correctly, but the error persists.
Here's what I have tried:

Ensuring that SigUsb.dll and all its dependencies are 64-bit.
Setting the environment variable PATH to include the directory where the DLL resides.
Running the application with administrative privileges.

Any insights into why Java might still be unable to load the DLL or suggestions for additional troubleshooting steps would be appreciated.

What did you do to find out what is missing?

i just solved it, the problem was that SigUsb.dll need microsoft visual C++ 2008 y 2010 redistribution to work properly
